# Updating Column Name of a Table together with its dependent UDFs/USPs

Tags: sql-server, database, user-defined-functions

I don't know if this already has an answer as I wasn't able to find it, but if so please provide the link.

Column names are used in User Defined Stored Procedures and Functions when accessing certain columns in a table. But what if I want to edit the column name in a table and I have called that column name a lot of times in multiple usp's/udf's.

I am currently using SQL Server and obviously it will not let me update a table column since it is called in multiple existing usp's/udf's. Is there a way to update the column name of a table together with the column names in those usp's/udf's?

Comment: Short answer - No :) renaming a column in a table is a real PITA and to be avoided if at all possible,

Comment: Yes I thought of that but I just wondered if there is such a way. If there is an existing table with poorly named columns I would like to edit that but then if there a lot of dependent usp/udf then its a hard work except if there was actually a way

Comment: You could use third party tooling like [APEX Search](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-search.aspx) to search where it's used, but you will still need to update all dependent objects. And this doesn't search in SSRS, SSIS, PowerBI, ... or other applications that might use the column directly.